# Unrecognized attribute 'requestPageSize' in Web.config

Tags: configuration, web-config, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm developing an application on Umbraco 7, but I'm encountering this error:

[image]

I tried modifying the `web.config` by removing the line but it didn't work.
Also I tried different values for `requestPageSize` but none of them solved the issue.

Anybody have an idea where this error came from?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think there is a config setting called that?

Comment: This happens in my `web.config` so I assume there is. If this is what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully I found an answer [here](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/95480-unrecognized-attribute-requestpagesize-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sensitive#comment-301871).

Basically the `web.config` file somehow got corrupted perhaps after installing a few packages, and what I did to solve the problem was to change the line showed in the error to:

```
<trace enabled="false" 
    requestLimit="10" 
    pageOutput="false" 
    traceMode="SortByTime" 
    localOnly="true" />
```

and also this bit of code as suggested in the link:

```
<requestFiltering>
  <requestLimits maxQueryString="52428800"/>
</requestFiltering>
```

And it worked again!